# Saving post likes in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-api

I'm making a social-media like websites where users can post text/images and like them, but I've ran into a problem. I know that I will store posts in Firestore, but where should I store likes? I can't store them in Firestore, because liking/disliking a post will waste 1 write operation(there is 600k write operations in the pay-as-you go tier). Should I store likes in Realtime database?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the 600k number from (it's always best to include links to where you get information from), but recommend checking out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters for a solution implementing higher throughput counters on Firestore, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore to help you pick the recommended database for the use-case.

Comment: Hey, the 600k writes is from [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: That's a long page, and I don't see any relevant 600k number in there when I search. Can you be more specific (that's *also* always a good idea)? Also: did you have a look at the distributed counters solution and database recommender I linked?

Comment: Hey, if you scroll to the "Blaze plan calculator" section and find Firestore you can see that free quota includes 600,000 writes.

Comment: ah, the calculator. Thanks for clarifying. This is the **free** quota on the paid plan though. It's not the limit of the plan, merely when you have to start paying for additional use.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> liking/disliking a post will waste 1 write operation(there is 600k
> write operations in the pay-as-you go tier).

The **free tier** (Spark plan) includes 20k writes per day (roughly 600k per month), and after that it will cost approximately $0.18 per 100k writes per month depending on your region [Writes Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing).

Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of writes in this scenario because if you have enough users on your app to be making 600k likes in a month, then your app (hopefully) has some revenue coming in.

The main issue is that a single Firestore document can only handle 1 write per second (can exceed in short term bursts). This is only an issue for you if you're storing all of those likes on a single document, which I assume you are as it makes sense to reduce reads. As Frank mentioned, to get around this issue you can look into distributed counters [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Another option as you mentioned is to store likes in RTDB. RTDB and Firestore work well together, as long as you're properly managing the data in both places. If you choose to store likes in RTDB beware of the following which may be relevant for your use case:

- RTDB can only have 100 concurrent connections on the Spark plan, and 200k on the Blaze plan. To scale past that (on the Blaze plan) you'll need to shard your data across multiple databases
- A single RTDB database has a current limit of 1k writes per second
- You can't perform batch writes across multiple Firebase services. For example, if you need to update a Firestore document at the same time as write to RTDB and want to make sure they succeed or fail as a group

You won't find a definite "yes" or "no" to your question. I've seen it implemented both ways, and they both work equally as well.

As Frank mentioned, you should look here [Firestore vs RTDB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) to pick which is best for you